# Coalesce<Integer> ClassCastException, trying to cast to Long

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I'm trying to use Coalesce on my query for returning 0 instead of NULL when I'm doing a SUM and there is no rows.

Here's my code :

```
...
Root<ArticleBean> rootArticle = cq.from(ArticleBean.class);
Coalesce<Integer> coalesce = cb.coalesce();
coalesce.value(cb.sum(rootArticle.get("quantity")));
coalesce.value(0);
cq.select(coalesce);

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

return (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
```

And the exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long
    at the line of the return.
```

Why does it try to cast the result to Long ?

Especially when I'm using a Coalesce<Integer> and the method sum() returns an Expression<Integer>...

I know that I can do something like that :

```
((Long) query.getSingleResult()).intValue()
```

But I'm a little curious and I would like to know why it tries to cast to Long.